# Digest authentication with encrypted stored password in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, basic-authentication, digest-authentication

I would like to implement digest authentication on my website. However, i have a user table with encrypted user table. I know that i can encrypt $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] if i use basic authentication. How can we use the same method for digest authentication?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: I need a workaround for encrypted password in db

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
define('MY_REALM', 'THIS IS A SECURE FACILITY, AND I MEAN THAT UNIRONICALLY');
$valid = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) {
    // Use your DB here; prepared statements are your friend:
    $userData = $user->getByUsername($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']); 
    if (!empty($userData)) {
        $valid = password_verify($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], $userData['password_hash']);
    }
}
if (!$valid) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="'.MY_REALM.'"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
}
```

There's little benefit to the HTTP digest authentication method. Just use HTTPS on your website and store passwords with `password_hash()` and use `password_verify()` to check them.